# logic to get consensus sequence

Tags: bioinformatics, consensus

I have a set of aligned sequences in fasta format. I want to get consensus out of the alignment. In case of most of the sites one of the base is showing maximum occurrence. In case of sites where two or more bases occur equal number of times, which base should be taken. An example is given below:

```
>Seq_1
ATGCGA
>Seq_2
AT-CGT
>Seq_3
AT-CCG
>Seq_4
AT-CCC
>Seq_5
AA-CT-
```

As per the conventions this will be the consensus

```
Site      : 1 2 3 4 5     6
Consensus : A T G C [G/C] N
```

But this output of the consensus sequence will throw an error when aligned with other sequences. So what should be done in such scenario and how to get consensus for such sites?

Answer (score 0):

You could also ask this question at Biostars.

However, these are my suggestions.

1) several packages exist to calculate consensus sequences. It may be worth using a known package.
2) If you want to create your own algorithm, have a look at the IUPAC nucleotide code (e.g. [here](http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms/iupac.html)). According to convention a  G/C would be represented by "S"

Comment: I have created code for this, but the problem is applications wouldn't accept such sequences with letters other than ATGC and also having multiple bases in a sequence at a site will obviously pose problem during alignment.

Comment: what applications are you using? Do you actually get an error?

Comment: One error that I get is invalid characters error, even then I have the option of ignoring such error. If I ignore such errors, it is creating gaps in other sequences. Also it is just ignoring letters S, Y and N. I am using MEGA 4.0 for my analysis. Also even if the application doesn't throw an error, it still is a glitch with data, which will eventually somehow affect the alignment.

Comment: It isn't really a "glitch" in the data. The data does not have ambiguity, it appears that you are artificially introducing ambiguity through the consensus approach. Why would you not just align all sequences as is? Why do you want to build a consensus sequence first and then perform an alignment again?

Comment: the information that I have is of aligned sequences only. Even the example that I gave above is that of aligned sequences.

Comment: @SRKR, I guess I am just confused about what you want to do once you calculate the consensus sequences. Based on your question, it appears that you will use the consensus sequence in another application. It would help us to know what the next step in your "pipeline" will be.

Answer (score 0):

Most consensus callers take quality into account to find not only the most frequent base but also the base with the highest confidence.

For example, in the old sanger days, an algorithm that did this was the Churchill-Waterman consensus calling algorithm.  There were also modified versions to suit your needs (for example, versions that did not call ambiguities)

Comment: true, but in this case there is no quality information (or is there?). I am not sure why the OP is calculating consensus in the first place...